# When starting to pedal, it takes half a rotation to "catch"

Tags: mountain-bike, drivetrain-slipping

While power pedaling on my mountain bike, when I coast for a second, it takes a half a circle on my crank to catch. Can anyone tell me the problem?

Comment: There are a half-dozen different possible causes. Most likely the chain is slipping part way off the front cog, and that's most likely caused by a sticky freewheel/freehub which is "pushing" the chain forward while coasting.

Comment: Can you look down and see what the chain is doing, while you coast then pedal again?   Need a clear space of road where you can do this safely.

Comment: If you hang the bike up and spin the pedals, does it do the same?

Comment: Most likely a bad free hub or one in need of lubrication. Another thing to check for is grass in the rear sprockets. Use a smallish stick to clean the muck in the rear cassette.

Answer (score 2):

If chain us not slipping then id say you have a busted freehub by the sound of it.

Take the cassette off, remove the freehub inspect the paws check for excess grease or lack of.

Otherwise look at a new freehub body. I had the same issue you describe last week.